# Change the position of slots for processing

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

New slots are added to a scene sequentially. I have a cleanup free form slot that handles any input that slots higher in the order have not handled. It has to be the last slot to be processed. But when I want to add a new slot it becomes the last slot so it is never processed. There seems to be no facility to reorder the slots to avoid this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is something that is seriously lacking in the UI right now. (You also can't reorder Intents, and they're handled in order as well.)

The only solution I know of is to use the [gactions command line tool](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) to download the project, edit the .yaml file for the scene in question, and then re-upload the project using gactions again.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the SDK but, as ever, Google lets you down.